# Fill in the Dashes : Part 4b of 10 - Subject Who?

Tags: word, knowledge

This is part of the [Fill in the Dashes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Fill%20in%20the%20Dashes%22) series of puzzles.

Example : F_ in the B_ ⇒ Fill in the Blanks

Some of the words will be Juxtaposed as in

e.g. : C_ K_ S_ 10 ⇒ Clark Kent Superman (S)

The number represents the position of letter in the solution to be extracted to be eventually used to find the link between the various clues.

---

B_ L_ O_ 7

B_ T_ 3

B_ D_ 3

D_ U_ 4

E_ G_ G_ W_ 3

J_ + R_  1

D_ P_ 1

M_ R_ 9

R_ R_ 17

A_ T_ 6

C_ 1

G_ N_ O_ Y_ 2

D_ T_ 6

I_ S_ 7

E_ T_ 9

O_ S_ T_ W_ W_ 5

Hint 1 (Should be enough)

> This time, the clues lead to a popular actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's :

> DiCaprio's movies

B_ L_ O_ 7

> Body of Lies (L)

B_ T_ 3

> The Beach (E)

B_ D_ 3

> Blood Diamond (O)

D_ U_ 4

> Django Unchained (N)

E_ G_ G_ W_ 3

> What's Eating Gilbert Grape (A)

J_ + R_ 1

> Romeo + Juliette (R)

D_ P_ 1

> Don's Plum (D)

M_ R_ 9

> Marvin's Room (O)

R_ R_ 17

> Revolutionary Road (D)

A_ T_ 6

> The Aviator (I)

C_ 1

> Celebrity (C)

G_ N_ O_ Y_ 2

> Gangs of New York (A)

D_ T_ 6

> The Departed (P)

I_ S_ 7

> Shutter Island (R)

E_ T_ 9

> Total Eclipse (I)

O_ S_ T_ W_ W_ 5

> The Wolf of Wall Street (O)

The letter obviously gives:

> Leonardo DiCaprio

Comment: oh dangit you beat me to it :(

Comment: @TroyAndABed Congrulations !!! That was awesome !!!

Answer (score 3):

B_ L_ O_ 7

> Body of Lies, L

B_ T_ 3

> The Beach, E

B_ D_ 3

> Blood Diamond, O

D_ U_ 4

> Django Unchained, N

E_ G_ G_ W_ 3

> What's Eating Gilbert Grape, A

J_ + R_ 1

> Romeo + Juliet, R

D_ P_ 1

> Don's Plum, D

M_ R_ 9

> Marvin's Room, O

R_ R_ 17

> Revolutionary Road, D

A_ T_ 6

> The Aviator, I

C_ 1

> Celebrity, C

G_ N_ O_ Y_ 2

> Gangs of New York, A

D_ T_ 6

> The Departed, P

I_ S_ 7

> Shutter Island, R

E_ T_ 9

> Total Eclipse, I

O_ S_ T_ W_ W_ 5

> The Wolf of Wall Street, O

Taking all of the letters gives us:

> Leonardo DiCaprio!

Comment: Congrulations !!! That was awesome !!!